# LINQ Query to filter Data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, filter

I have a table which contains `Branch Ids` and `Department Ids`. I have three branches and 1st branch has only 1 Department, the 2nd branch has two departments and 3rd branch has three Departments.

Now, I need to write a query to find branches which have department 1 but doesn't have dept. 2 and dept. 3.

This is just an example, I have a much more complex scenario which is very dynamic. I am using this example to put forward my question.

I am attaching the picture to understand the problem.

[image]

Here's query:

```
db.ConnectedBRDE.Where(x => x.DeptId == 1 && x.DeptId != 2)
                .Select(x => x.BranchId)
                .ToList();
```

This query is giving my all three Branches, whereas, I only need branch 1 because this is the only branch which doesn't have department 2.

This part  `&& x.DeptId != 2` is wrong, I guess. What should I write here to make my filter working?

Comment: are you keeping both Branches and Departments in a single table?

Comment: This is a bridge Table that contains `BranchId` and `DepartmentId`.

Comment: Try `db.ConnectedBRDE.GroupBy(x => x.BranchId).Where(y => y.Count() == 1 && y.First().DeptId == 1);`

Comment: @AshirK. accourding to your image and your query, it will return 3 rows of BranchId s. so, `&& x,DeptId != 2` works just fine and it's about your whole query

Comment: Is this a dynamic solution @StephenMuecke ? I think it was not much different than  && x.DeptId != 2 && x.DeptId != 3

Comment: @HüseyinBurakKaradag, Its not the same at all :)

Comment: @AshirK. if you have access to Branch and Department models, i suggest use this query: `Branches.Where(b=>b.Departments.All(d=>d.Id != 2) && b.Departments.Any(d=>d.Id==1))`

Comment: @StephenMuecke will your solution work if I have 10 Departments and I  only need branches which have departments until 8 or I will need to change count equation?

Comment: All I could do is give you a solution for what you stated in the question - I do not know what your _much more complex scenario which is very dynamic_ is :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right, it's not the same :)

Comment: You should realize if `x.DeptId == 1` then by definition `x.DeptId != 2` and the second clause accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't think you should have `y.Count() == 1` but rather `y.All(z => z.DeptId != 2)`.

Comment: @NetMage, That does not take into account the OP also wanted to exclude `DeptId = 3`

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are right. It should be `y.All(z => z.DeptId == 1)`.

Comment: @Ashir K. did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried your technique to do it separately and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Muecke's comment does indeed work.

I have tested it in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lrP3aQ).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<TestClass> lstOfItems = new List<TestClass>();

        var itemOne = new TestClass(){BranchName = "Branch One", BranchId = 1, DeptId = 1};
        var itemTwo = new TestClass(){BranchName = "Branch Two", BranchId = 2, DeptId = 1};
        var itemThree = new TestClass(){BranchName = "Branch Two", BranchId = 2, DeptId = 2};
        var itemFour = new TestClass(){BranchName = "Branch Three", BranchId = 3, DeptId = 1};
        var itemFive = new TestClass(){BranchName = "Branch Three", BranchId = 3, DeptId = 2};
        var itemSix = new TestClass(){BranchName = "Branch Three", BranchId = 3, DeptId = 3};

        lstOfItems.Add(itemOne);
        lstOfItems.Add(itemTwo);
        lstOfItems.Add(itemThree);
        lstOfItems.Add(itemFour);
        lstOfItems.Add(itemFive);
        lstOfItems.Add(itemSix);

        var myList = lstOfItems.GroupBy(x => x.BranchName).Where(y => y.Count() == 1 && y.First().DeptId == 1).ToList();

        foreach(var item in myList){
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
        }

        // Output
        // Branch One

    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string BranchName {get;set;}
    public int BranchId {get;set;}  
    public int DeptId {get;set;}
}
```

Basically, once all of the records are grouped by `BranchName` property, then we want to count all of the records under each branch name.. and if the count equals `1` then that means that branch only has `1` record.. and then we find the `DeptId` of that record and if it equals `1` then that satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think bellowing code is what are you looking for

```
var list = new List<Model>();
list.Add(new Model(1, 1));
list.Add(new Model(2, 1));
list.Add(new Model(2, 2));
list.Add(new Model(3, 1));
list.Add(new Model(3, 2));
list.Add(new Model(3, 3));

var notValidBranchIds = list.Where(x => x.DeptId == 2 || x.DeptId == 3).Select(x => x.BranchId);
var result = list.Where(x => x.DeptId == 1 && !notValidBranchIds.Contains(x.BranchId)).Select(x => x.BranchId);

// you can also use this. It solve the problem in a line
var betterResult = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.DeptId })
   .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(a => a.DeptId == 1))
   .Where(y => y != null)
   .ToList();
```

return only first branchId's record.

Hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to Branch and Department models, i suggest use this query: `Branches.Where(b=>b.Departments.All(d=>d.Id != 2) && b.Departments.Any(d=>d.Id==1))`